# Googlecharts - Annotation Chart - First column must contain date or date time

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to plot an annotation chart with google chart. However, I get the error "First column must be date or datetime". If I were to change the chart type to be area or line for example, it works fine.

Here's the javascript section of the "View page source" content of the final HTML page on which I'm expecting a graph to be drawn

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded FROM server.
            var data_1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['ACTIVITY DATE TIME','ACTIVITY DURATION'],['2015-10-31 02:00:00',503],['2015-11-01 09:26:00',4],['2015-11-01 11:30:00',2],['2015-11-01 19:33:00',2],['2015-11-02 01:15:00',2],['2015-11-02 03:09:00',2],['2015-11-02 07:04:00',2],['2015-11-02 09:47:00',2],['2015-11-02 11:10:00',2]]);

            var options = {
                displayAnnotations: true    
            };

            var chart_1 = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('plot1'));
            chart_1.draw(data_1, options);
            }
            ;
        </script>
```

Could I request help please to figure out the problem? Is there any typecasting needed or anything whatsoever to get this working please?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['annotationchart']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded FROM server.
            var data_1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?php echo (implode(",", $chart_array_1)); ?>]);

            var options = {
                displayAnnotations: true
            };

            var chart_1 = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('plot1'));
            chart_1.draw(data_1, options);
            }
            ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to cast those `strings` as `Dates`.

```
var data = [
  ['ACTIVITY DATE TIME', 'ACTIVITY DURATION'],
  ['2015-10-31 02:00:00', 503],
  ['2015-11-01 09:26:00', 4],
  ['2015-11-01 11:30:00', 2],
  ['2015-11-01 19:33:00', 2],
  ['2015-11-02 01:15:00', 2],
  ['2015-11-02 03:09:00', 2],
  ['2015-11-02 07:04:00', 2],
  ['2015-11-02 09:47:00', 2],
  ['2015-11-02 11:10:00', 2]
];

// or var data = [<?php echo (implode(",", $chart_array_1)); ?>]

for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
    data[i][0] = new Date(data[i][0]); // converting strings to Dates

google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['annotationchart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded FROM server.
  var data_1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

  var options = {
    displayAnnotations: true
  };

  var chart_1 = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('plot1'));
  chart_1.draw(data_1, options);
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/brxa99yd/)

Comment: Hello crclayton - Thank you very much for this. Just a bit tricky thing. I get the data through PHP ( PHP queries database & populates the array). How could I get the typecasting working with the details stored in the PHP array "$chart_array_1"? Please can you guide me?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should just be able to assign the result of the `PHP` query to the variable `data`, then modify it the same way with JavaScript. See my comment in the answer.

Comment: That's cool. Got that to work. Thank you very much. But the graph is not being plot. Same problem as in your JSFIDDLE. I get the error a[jc] is not a function.

Comment: I'm not sure what that error means, I think it's related to other code you're running. The JSFiddle works on my end [see screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HdWhZ.png), are you sure it's not working for you?

Comment: you're right. It's the firefox problem. Chrome works brilliantly. THank you very much again. Appreciate your help.